# Query for finding the SUM of salary of each company

Tags: query

We have two tables that are structured as shown below:

- `company (cid, cname)`
- `emp(eid, ename, cid, salary)`

What should be query for finding o/p as follows?

```
cname salary  (sum of salary with particular company name)
```

Sample data for the `Comp` table:

```
cid | cname
--- |-------
12  | It
13  | comp
14  | Mech
```

Sample data for the `Emp` table:

```
eid |ename |cid |salary
----|------|----|-----
1   |xyz   |12  |300 ---]This sum of It company needs to add in sub total
2   |abc   |12  |400 ---] of 12.
3   |rst   |13  |500
4   |pqr   |14  |200
```

Expected output:

```
cname |salary 
------|------
  It  |700
 comp |500
 Mech |200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was able to understand from your query is that you need sum of salary paid to employees of all the companies. Here is the solution

Also you need to pass the additional filter parameters in where clause before group by clause

Hope this will help

```
SELECT CName,SUM(Salary) AS SalaryPaidByCompany
FROM cmpny INNER JOIN emp ON cmpny.cid=emp.cid
GROUP BY Cname
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT c.cid,SUM(e.salary) as 'salary' from Comp c,Emp e 
where c.cid = e.cid
group by c.cid
```

Comment: `as 'salary'` is invalid standard SQL. Single quotes are for string constants, not for identifiers

Comment: The call out is for "SQL" not "SQL Server".  However, for whatever this is work, it would work on SQL Server 2014.